# Getting the wrong outputs for my SQL queries-why is it so?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 8 tables-

```
Course(Courseno,Coursename,dept)
Section(Courseno,Sectionno),
Student(ssn,firstname,lastname,street,zip,city,state),
Enrolls(ssn,Sectionno,Courseno),Exam(Courseno,Sectionno,Examno),
Classroom(roomno,building,capacity),
conducted_in(roomno,building,Courseno,Sectionno,Examno) 
Takes(ssn,Courseno,Sectionno,Examno,result)
```

I am writing two queries. 1st query is to Get the course names and course numbers which have 2 or more students. I wrote it as

```
mysql> SELECT c.CourseNo,Course_Name FROM STUDENT s INNER JOIN ENROLLS e 
ON s.SSN=e.SSN INNER JOIN COURSE c ON e.CourseNo=c.CourseNo WHERE e.SSN>=2;
```

and i get the output as

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| CourseNo | Course_Name           |
+----------+-----------------------+
| CSC11    | Computer Architecture |
| CSC12    | VLSI                  |
| CSC12    | VLSI                  |
+----------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

for the 2nd query it says to Obtain information (exam number, course number and section number) about the exams taking place in building ‘RVR’. Along with that get the room’s capacity, room number and its building name.
i wrote the query as-

```
mysql> SELECT e.ExamNo,e.CourseNo,e.SectionNo,cr.RoomNo,cr.Building FROM EXAM e 
INNER JOIN CONDUCTED_IN ci ON ci.ExamNo=e.ExamNo INNER JOIN CLASS_ROOM cr 
ON cr.Building=ci.Building='RVR';
```

and got the output as

> Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Despite the building RVR being present in the table

What mistakes am I making since I dont get the desirred output?? please help me.

Comment: try adding where clause with - 'RVR' instead of using it on join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following for your `Question 2`, you have not added `WHERE` condition in your query. this was the issue `on cr.Building=ci.Building='RVR'`

```
select e.ExamNo,
    e.CourseNo,
    e.SectionNo,
    cr.RoomNo,
    cr.Building 
from EXAM e 
JOIN CONDUCTED_IN ci 
on ci.ExamNo=e.ExamNo 

JOIN CLASS_ROOM cr 
on cr.Building=ci.Building

WHERE cr.Building = 'RVR';
```

for `Question 1`, you forgot to use `DISTINCT` and same result can be achieve by `GROUP BY` as well.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT c.CourseNo,
    Course_Name 
FROM STUDENT s 

JOIN ENROLLS e 
ON s.SSN=e.SSN 

JOIN COURSE c 
ON e.CourseNo=c.CourseNo 

WHERE e.SSN>=2;
```

Comment: thanks..i got it running what about the first one tho?